# Counting number of directories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to count the number of directories I have in a directory. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

SET /a counter=0

for /D %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    echo folder %counter%: %%~nxa
    SET /a counter=%counter%+1
)

endlocal
```

It is printing just

```
folder 0: folder1
folder 0: folder2
...
```

So I think the counter is getting reset to 0 each time it loops, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: You wrote `SET \a` instead of `SET /a`.

Comment: I fixed that, but am getting the same result. The counter is staying as 0.

Comment: Please see articles about `delayed expansion` by using the `search` facility on the top bar

Comment: `set /A counter+=1` avoids the need of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansiom.html); you need to put `echo %counter%` behind the loop to get the final count though...

Comment: An alternative method: `dir /B /A:D "%folder%\*" | find /C /V ""`; the output can be captured by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)...

Comment: `dir /b /a:d | find /c /v ""` seems like an easier solution to me.  Or `for /f %%I in ('dir /b /a:d ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a foldercount=%%I`  **Edit:** @aschipfl, great minds think alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing *and* reading the variable `counter` within the same block of code, namely the `for` loop, you need to establish [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); otherwise you always get the value present *before* the block is executed:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

set /A counter=0

for /D %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    echo folder !counter!: %%~nxa
    SET /a counter=!counter!+1
)

endlocal
```

Anyway, `set /A` does not require explicit variable expansion, you could simply write `set /A counter=counter+1`, or even simpler, `set /A counter+=1`, so you do not need delayed expansion for this. For echoing the value `!counter!` in the loop however, you still need delayed expansion though.

---

There is an even easier approach to count the number of folders, using [`dir /B /A:D`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to return a plain folder list, [piped by `|`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) into [`find /C`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) to cound the number of received lines:

```
dir /B /A:D "%folder%\*" | find /C /V ""
```

You can use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the result and store it in a variable:

```
for /F %%a in ('
    dir /B /A:D "%folder%\*" ^| find /C /V ""
') do (
    set "counter=%%a"
)
```

Note the escaped pipe `^|` needed herein.

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell can be used:

```
PS C:\Users\pwatson> Get-ChildItem -Directory | Measure-Object | Select-Object -Property Count

Count
-----
   44
```